# MariaDB docker access denied error with healthcheck script when root password is set, even with MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER?

Tags: docker, mariadb

If i dont' set `root` user password, the service works fine and the healthcheck takes a few seconds, then reports the service as "healthy":

> Set MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER to a non-empty value to create the mysql@locahost database user. This user is especially useful for a variety of health checks and backup scripts. The mysql@localhost user gets USAGE privileges by default.

```yml
db:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
        MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: true
        MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER: true
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "/usr/local/bin/healthcheck.sh", "--connect"]
        start_period: 5
        timeout: 3s
        interval: 5s
        retries: 5
```

As soon set the `root` user password (removing volumes, restarting docker compose etc.), I got the following errors **caused by the healthcheck script**, every 5 seconds:

> app-db | 2023-05-14 20:10:55 27 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO)

So the question is: how do I use the `mysql@localhost` database user to run the healtcheck script, when a root password is set?

**EDIT**: this work when I run inside the db container: `/usr/local/bin/healthcheck.sh --su=mysql --connect` however, in the logs, I still get *[Warning] Access denied for user 'mysql'@'127.0.0.1'*.

Comment: It'd be better to configure the health-check to use the right password.

Comment: Your datadir has been initialized and the root user does have a password already, which is why none of the provided env variables have an effect.

Comment: I'm contemplating making a `mysql@127.0.0.1` (+`::1`) user for the `MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER=1` case in the official image. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it as the system user named `mysql`, so it authenticates through the socket and not the password. The `healthcheck.sh` script already has a [flag](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/29e2cbb9b2339627497fb3247942bd802ec81191/10.11/healthcheck.sh#L259) that does that for you. Change your healthcheck line to:

```yaml
test: ["CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--su-mysql", "--connect"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't really help. Found this after asking my question: https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/430